# Get encoding, read & write with this encoding in android?

Tags: java, android

How can I check what encoding is used in a file, then read the file with this encoding and the save it with the same or a different encoding in Android. I haven't seen any good options for this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [juniversalchardet](http://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/) library to automatically detect the encoding. It has an array of per-defined encoding set to look for.

*Currently supported encodings are:*

```
Chinese
    ISO-2022-CN
    BIG5
    EUC-TW
    GB18030
    HZ-GB-23121 

Cyrillic
    ISO-8859-5
    KOI8-R
    WINDOWS-1251
    MACCYRILLIC
    IBM866
    IBM855 

Greek
    ISO-8859-7
    WINDOWS-1253 

Hebrew
    ISO-8859-8
    WINDOWS-1255 

Japanese
    ISO-2022-JP
    SHIFT_JIS
    EUC-JP 

Korean
    ISO-2022-KR
    EUC-KR 

Unicode
    UTF-8
    UTF-16BE / UTF-16LE
    UTF-32BE / UTF-32LE / X-ISO-10646-UCS-4-34121 / X-ISO-10646-UCS-4-21431 

Others
    WINDOWS-1252
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Do you have a suggestion of how to read and write to and from a string with the encoding in android?

Comment: They have all the example codes available on their project site.

Comment: Where? I can only find how read the encoding. Not reading the content.

Comment: reading a file is up to you, see [this](http://huuah.com/android-writing-and-reading-files/)